# Extract ranges from multiple workbooks / sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a range of cells (ex: L1:S22) which will send email alert when the values are > 0 in that particular range from active spreadsheet

So far its only sending from the active spreadsheet range. I want it to be called from all other workbooks which is stored in a folder and send email according to that

```
function CheckSales(){

var app = SpreadsheetApp;
var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

var data=activeSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

var emailAddress=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2").getValue();
var resultArr=[];

//To Loop through the whole data Rows
for(var i=1;i<data.length;i++)
  {
    //Takes columns from L to S (To loop through the Columns)
    for(var j=11;j<19;j++)
      {
        var cellVal=data[i][j];
        Logger.log(cellVal)
        if(cellVal>0)
        {
           //Stores the Part No, Month Header Value of the Column, Cell Value which is greater then 0
           resultArr.push([data[i][0],data[0][j],cellVal])
        }
      }
  }
  if(resultArr.length>0)
  {
    var subject = 'Range exceeded Alert';

    //Creates a body through the obtained values
    var body='';
    for(var m=0;m<resultArr.length;m++)
       {
         body+="For Part No "+resultArr[m][0].toString()+" and Month "+resultArr[m][1].toString()+", Value is "+resultArr[m][2].toString()+"<br>";
       }

      MailApp.sendEmail({to:emailAddress,subject:subject,htmlBody:body});
   }

}
```

now the output showing the part number which have exceeded the values after 6 months.

For Part No 60009257001 and Month 7MO, Value is 800
For Part No 60009259007 and Month 12MO, Value is 28032
For Part No 60009260011 and Month >18MO, Value is 74670
For Part No 60009260012 and Month 12MO, Value is 17600
For Part No 60009260013 and Month 10MO, Value is 26389

I expect the output to show all the part numbers from different workbooks

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i in activeSheet) {
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(activeSheet[i])
    var sheet = app.getActiveSheet();
    var data = activeSheet[i].getDataRange().getValues();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through the different data ranges in the same way as done here with "data" Variable.

For example,

```
var data=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Battery').getDataRange().getValues();

//For Loop for data

data2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Other Sheet").getDataRange().getValues();

//for Loop for data2
```

Comment: The problem here is that I need to add the sheet code every time right? is there any other alternative like VLOOKUP in this app script where it can search for the files inside the folder and pull the data?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I found another way by looping through sheets to look for the value. for (var i in activeSheet) {

  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(activeSheet[i])
  var sheet = app.getActiveSheet();
  var data = activeSheet[i].getDataRange().getValues();